# very need with simple sample Sound Visualisation

Tags: visual-c++, visualization, ms-media-foundation

Could any help me with Sound\Music Visualisation simple example code (oscillogramm) on C++?

Is it possible to make it without registrating MFT DLL as in DShow\Scope - simple manual connecting source-visualisation?

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly you're asking?  I'm a bit confused.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. ²

Comment: I asked simple source on c++ of Sound Visualisation.  I tried DShow, but it is very difficult to write own filters and need registrate dll. I write music player with visualisation on Media Foundation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Sample Grabber Sink configured to accept audio samples (audio IMFMediaType). The data from the captured audio samples can then be visualized using DirectX, GDI or even simple controls like progress bars. 
Check this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh184779(v=vs.85).aspx
The OnProcessSample function printf's some info about each audio sample. You can use it as a starting point for your visualization code.

Comment: Thanks VuVirt, but followed Your link I see: "Note  The Source Reader is an alternative to the Sample Grabber Sink and has a simpler programming model." I try Source Reader now.

Comment: Hello VuVirt! How in Your opinion is possible to get state of sound every 20-100 ms from MF or Sample Grabber Sink?

Comment: @Andrei I think you'll need to accumulate the audio samples and buffer them and process the buffer according to your needs on every 20-100ms.

Comment: VuVirt! As I say IMHO Microsoft gave wrong name to Samples. Before it always be 1-4 bytes but in MF it is big piece of audiodata. Or  I m wrong? Give me ANY example how get state about arriving very small piece of audio data 1-4 bytes or 20-100 ms at least.

Comment: Maybe this sample will help you but it is directshow: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd377557(v=vs.85).aspx.
You need to implement a circular buffer and push the sample data into it until you have 100 ms available and render from the circular buffer.

Comment: I know Scope example. DShow is some crossed technology for experienced programmers not only me. It need GraphEditor or registrating dll. Oh if You could give me example how to make it without DShow!!! or simple bit from DShow but without .dll –

Comment: DirectShow has the same mechanism: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd376984(v=vs.85).aspx. You can use it in conjunction with Scope sample to make the visualization inside your app without dlls. Sorry, I cannot help you any further. You'll have to do it yourself.